# Change context path of an Entreprise Application (ear) in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

It is possible to change the context path of a web application (`war`) in glassfish, but is there any solution to change the context path of an Entreprise application (`ear`)?

I tried to change it from `glassfish-web.xml` like this:

```
<!-- Default context -->
<context-root>/module1-web</context-root>

<!-- New context -->
<context-root>/erp/module1-web</context-root>
```

but it does not work. I tried to change it from the server but there is no way to change it.

**Web application context path**

[image: Web application context path]

Is there any solution for that problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a solution for your problem.

You need to place a file named `application.xml` in the `META-INF` folder of your EAR.

Here is an example how the file could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <application-name>your_application</application-name>
  <display-name>your_application</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>your-war-file.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/your_desired_context</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>another-war-file.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/another/context/for/the/second/war/file</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>ejb-module-example.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

As you see you can also declare multiple web modules with different context paths.

You can generate the file with the [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/), for more information have a look at [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-context-root.html).

Here is an example how to use the plugin:

To make it work, you have to separate your web module (the WAR) to an extra maven project. Then you can reference it in the plugin configuration like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <applicationName>your_application</applicationName>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
                        <artifactId>your-web-module</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/your-web-module</contextRoot>
                        <excluded>false</excluded>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Thank you @unwichtich This should help me

Comment: Can you explain more the way with maven, with an exemple please?

Comment: I have added an example.