# project deployed correctly but server return 404 not found

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly-9

war project deployed correctly

[image]

but welcome.jsf page show me 404 however my url is correct 
'http://localhost:18080/shop-web/welcome.jsf '

web.xml file :

```
<display-name>shop-web</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add content of application.xml?

Comment: thank you mr Kysil for your response but i am new to J2EE and i'am using ear architecture ( EAR - EJB - WEB ) and using a wildfly 9.x as a server where i can find application.xml file,
however i configured the pom qnd the standalone file of the server and i am connected to my database ( mysql ) but the only problem is i can not acces to my jsf file via browser it keeps telling me that resources not found however in the server folder ( standelone deployements ) i can find my jsf files. 
I hope you can help and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, application servers (WildFly, Glassfish, etc.) are free to choose the context path for your web application. Usually, they come up with something like `/<full name of WAR file>`.

It is possible to influence this behaviour when WAR is included in EAR by adding `application.xml` deployment descriptor.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39246571/1091731) for discussion about `application.xml` and context path of web applications.